# How do I row bind repeated columns based on a column value?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

So basically I am trying to fix an excel spreadsheet that was copy pasted from a pivot table.

I had to do some pre processing to get rid of NaN values. The dataset looks like this.

```
                                          0                 1
0                                     Region       Banyule (C)
2                 None (includes bedsitters)            78/0.2
3                                  1 bedroom          1287/2.9
4                                 2 bedrooms         8457/19.4
5                                 3 bedrooms          21865/50
6                         4 or more bedrooms          11366/26
7              Number of bedrooms not stated           645/1.5
9    Average number of bedrooms per dwelling            3.1/--
10    Average number of people per household            2.6/--
11                                    Region       Bayside (C)
13                None (includes bedsitters)            97/0.3
14                                 1 bedroom          1054/3.2
15                                2 bedrooms         7939/23.9
16                                3 bedrooms        13731/41.3
17                        4 or more bedrooms        10031/30.1
18             Number of bedrooms not stated           419/1.3
20   Average number of bedrooms per dwelling            3.1/--
21    Average number of people per household            2.6/--
```

I did a transpose here
`tr=r_2011.T`

And what I get is.

```
 Region  Average number of people per household Region     Average number of people per household
 Banyule (C)                          2.7/--    Bayside(C)    2.6/--
```

However, I want to get the dataset to have it arranged in this structure.

```
Region       None (includes bedsitters) 1 bedroom 2 bedrooms 3 bedrooms 4 or more bedrooms
Banyule (C)  78/0.2                     1287/2.9  8457/19.4  21865/50  11366/26
Bayside (C)  97/0.3                     1054/3.2  7939/23.9  13731/41.3  10031/30.1
```

Not able to figure out whether pivot or melt methods can solve it.

Here is the link to file (https://drive.google.com/open?id=18p0qPiqOaPF1d8NgVVB_qIYNV_HbtXQo)

Comment: so you want just this row `Average number of people per household` returned for every region? or all the rows under it?

Comment: @anky_91I want all the rows under it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
# create an auxilary column "Region" from the row with 
# label "Region" and forward fill it for all rows
df['Region']= df['1'].where(df['0'] == 'Region', None)
df['Region'].ffill(inplace=True)
# add the original label and the region to the index
# and unstack it to align the attributes of the regions
df.set_index(['0', 'Region'], inplace=True)
df.unstack()
```

The output is:

```
Region                                   Banyule (C)  Bayside (C)
0                                                                
1 bedroom                                   1287/2.9     1054/3.2
2 bedrooms                                 8457/19.4    7939/23.9
3 bedrooms                                  21865/50   13731/41.3
4 or more bedrooms                          11366/26   10031/30.1
Average number of bedrooms per dwelling       3.1/--       3.1/--
Average number of people per household        2.6/--       2.6/--
None (includes bedsitters)                    78/0.2       97/0.3
Number of bedrooms not stated                645/1.5      419/1.3
Region                                   Banyule (C)  Bayside (C)
```

The dataframe I used is built up like this from the output in the question. So 0 is the column in which you find the labels like "Region" and 1 is the column in which you find the corresponding values like "Banyule (C)":

```
csv=""";0;1
0;Region;Banyule (C)
2;None (includes bedsitters);78/0.2
3;1 bedroom;1287/2.9
4;2 bedrooms;8457/19.4
5;3 bedrooms;21865/50
6;4 or more bedrooms;11366/26
7;Number of bedrooms not stated;645/1.5
9;Average number of bedrooms per dwelling;3.1/--
10;Average number of people per household;2.6/--
11;Region;Bayside (C)
13;None (includes bedsitters);97/0.3
14;1 bedroom;1054/3.2
15;2 bedrooms;7939/23.9
16;3 bedrooms;13731/41.3
17;4 or more bedrooms;10031/30.1
18;Number of bedrooms not stated;419/1.3
20;Average number of bedrooms per dwelling;3.1/--
21;Average number of people per household;2.6/--"""

import io
import pandas as pd

sb=io.StringIO(csv)
df= pd.read_csv(sb, index_col=0, sep=';')
```

The code above assumes that your data is properly preaggregated and the index assigned is unique. If it is not unique, you can add an auxillary "Num" column, to make it unique. This would look like:

```
sb=io.StringIO(csv)
df= pd.read_csv(sb, index_col=0, sep=';')

# just rename the columns to have meaningfull names
df.columns= pd.Index(['Attribute', 'Value'])

# add the region info in a separate column
df['Region']= df['Value'].where(df['Attribute'] == 'Region', None)
df['Region'].ffill(inplace=True)

# now create an auxilary Num column that allows us to create
# a unique index based on Attribute, Region and Num
df['Num']= df.groupby(['Attribute', 'Region']).cumcount()+1

# filter out the row with the Region
df=df[df['Attribute'] != 'Region']

# set the index for unstack, that is the
# columns in the final index + the index used for the
# pivot like unstack operation 
df.set_index(['Attribute', 'Num', 'Region'], inplace=True)
df.unstack(['Region'])
```

In order to test it, you can add some lines to the csv string like:

```
22;Number of bedrooms not stated;213/2.1
23;Average number of bedrooms per dwelling;2.3/1.8
24;Average number of people per household;2.7/1.8
```

Comment: It makes sense what you are trying to do. But I am still getting an error.
(https://imgur.com/a/YAm6l2O)

Comment: It's always easier if data is provided. I just used your formatted table to parse it and it looks as if you have columns labelled '0' and '1'. '0' would be the column label and '1' the value that belongs to it. If they are named differently in your data, you just need to change the names, then it should work.

Comment: I added the data, I used. Hope it helps to customize it for your particular data. Btw. you know that we are no employees of stackoverflow and that we don't get paid for helping people here?

Comment: I have made the fixes its actually 1 instead of '1' and 0 instead of '0'. Here is the file. However, the last unstack command doesnt work. (https://drive.google.com/open?id=18p0qPiqOaPF1d8NgVVB_qIYNV_HbtXQo)

Comment: Using my data, I have only used the following code:
`import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("output.csv")
df['Region'] = df['1'].where(df['0'] == 'Region', None)
df['Region'].ffill(inplace=True)
df.set_index(['0', 'Region'], inplace=True)
df.unstack()`
The index has been set but the unstack won't work. The error says it won't reshape because of duplicate entries.

Comment: I see. If I just enter another row in my data with the same values for '0' and 'Region', i get the same phenomenon. Are the duplicate lines in your case wanted? if not, you proably have to aggregate your dataframe first, before you do the unstack, otherwise, you have to insert an auxillary variable that makes your index unique (I mean the part without the Region).

Comment: Now it should work. The problem is, that unstack has to know how to allign the column values. If the index is not unique, how should it know in which row it has to display a specific value? To allow this, you need to make the index unique. I added an example above.

Comment: Yea you are right about index not working due to duplicates. The creator of the dataset put a second set of duplicate region in somewhere and I dropped it using `df.drop_duplicates(subset=[0,'Region'], keep='last')`. I was able to set index. It worked as I intended.

Thanks a lot @jottbe. I wouldn't have been able to do this without you. I am preparing for a tutoring position at my uni by solving as many datasets as I can. Thanks a lot for your perseverance. I can't upvote because I am new :( So I have marked this as solved. You will get points for that.

Comment: I'm glad it helped in some way. Have fun with your tutoring position. Pandas is really fun, otherwise I wouldn't do this :-)